# htaccess - insert php script name into all URLs

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an application which requires an htaccess file in the directory `/tileserver/` that contains the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(tileserver\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ tileserver.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

what I need is for any URL request to tileserver/

to instead be

`tileserver/tileserver.php/`

but then if I add something like:

`RewriteRule ^tileserver/(.*)$ tileserver/tileserver.php/$1`

it has no effect. How do I write this rule?

**update** here is a line from the error log:

```
[Thu Dec 17 13:17:48.858560 2015] [negotiation:error] [pid 23573] [client 108.44.58.67:64411] AH00687: Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /var/www/html/tileserver/extra5 (None could be negotiated)., referer: http://107.170.120.88/tileserver/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request will start with `/` so you need to change it for

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/tileserver/(.*)$ /tileserver/tileserver.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hmmm, this didn't work. The htaccess file is in the "tileserver" directory - does it need to just work from the tileserver root? I tried:  `^(.*)$ tileserver.php/$1` also but that didn't work

Comment: are you sure .htaccess are activated on the server ?

Comment: Yes, I'm positive. It works for other purposes.

Comment: Can you add an sample of URL before & after rewrite you want please ?

Comment: Yes - thanks - it would be: http://107.170.120.88/tileserver/tileserver.php/extra5/11/331/794.png
instead of http://107.170.120.88/tileserver/extra5/11/331/794.png

Comment: so the rewrite rule i posted should works and transform to `/tileserver/extra5/11/331/794.png` to `/tileserver/tileserver.php/extra5/11/331/794.png`, i added the [L] flag to prevent extra Rule to be executed after if this one matched. To trace whats is going wrong you need to display rewrite logs : `RewriteLog "/usr/local/var/apache/logs/rewrite.log"` + `RewriteLogLevel 3` in your server configuration then if you don't know how to read log, please post them in your original post as edit

Comment: Ok, I've updated the question with the result of the log.

Comment: And do you have any rewrite log ?

Comment: No - I don't seem to be able to write to the log file. Would it be possible to chat briefly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33121/discussion-between-froggiz-and-mheavers).